# Regex - Match between 0 and 1 nested characters anywhere in quantified match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to write a regex for some specific naming attribute of a program, but it has some unusual parameters.

- The names may contain spaces
- The names may contain unicode characters
- The names may contain ' (apostrophe)
- The names may contain -
- The names may only contain **one** space, apostrophe, or hyphen each.
- The names may be between 3 and 48 characters in length.

I have the following regex, but it doesn't work with the spaces and such constraints.

`^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}'\-]{3,48})$`

I'm not sure how to nest the more specific constraints. When I try something like ..

`^(?:[']?[a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]{3,48})$`

It doesn't work unless the apostrophe is the first letter. I need it to check to see if the special character given is anywhere in the string, not just where it appears in specific sequence in the regex. I've got RegexBuddy and have been using it extensively, but it's not proving to be of any help in trying to figure this out.

Comment: Why do you have to use a single regex? Just write a function that tests the constraints separately. Also, what programming language?

Comment: It can only be a single regex. The language will be in C#. Due to specific constraints, the entire thing must be completely contained in a single expression. The validation mechanism used internally will only accept one expression.

Comment: Do you mean **all** unicode characters? Special characters and whitespace, too?

Comment: Yes, it's a very dumb requirement. The program that will be receiving the input is written in an old, old business BASIC language and it crashes on any kind of invalid input, but the API provided doesn't let us pass validation to our own software before it sends it to the receiving program. We tried just filtering the entry field with multiple expressions, but it tries to submit asynchronously. It's a horrible, horrible program that we have to plug into and it makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what it sounds like to me:

```
@"^(?!.*?\s.*?\s|.*?-.*?-|.*?'.*?').{3,48}$"
```

I don't know if that's perfect, but it looks close to me. I'm trying to figure out if the last `.` is too broad; if anyone wants to correct me I'll welcome it.

---

**Edit**: Never content to leave well enough alone, it occurs to me you could shorten this.

```
@"^(?!.*?([-'\s]).*?\1).{3,48}$"
```

would probably work, but I'm not sure if `foo-bar'baz'qux` would fool it. I don't *think* it would be a problem. You could give it a shot.

Comment: This is actually perfect. It is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I'm not sure why it works, but I will be picking it apart to try and figure it out. I basically couldn't figure out how to do recursive backpeddling inside of a single expression.

Comment: @Stacey: Glad to help! It's not actually recursive, it just repeats the tokens it's looking for. If you'd like a little more info about how it works, check here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @sln - Is that a problem? I thought `)` and `$` were allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see [)$] as matching anything in [a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}'-]

Comment: @sln - Based on the clarification in the comments, I think special characters are allowed, and the original regex was too narrow. @Stacey said all unicode characters are allowed to match. AFAIK the `.` is what they're looking for, but it could be swapped with `[a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]` if that's the preferred set. If so, the final `.` should be all that needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do it:

`/^(?!(?:.*[ ]){2})(?!(?:.*[']){2})(?!(?:.*[-]){2})(?=[a-zA-Z0-9 \p{L}'-]{3,48}$)/`

```
/
   ^                         # start of string
    (?!(?:.*[ ]){2})         # no greater than 1 space
    (?!(?:.*[']){2})         # no greater than 1 apostrophe
    (?!(?:.*[-]){2})         # no greater than 1 dash
    (?=[a-zA-Z0-9 \p{L}'-]{3,48}$)   # 3 - 48 characters of this class
/x
```

Comment: This is also extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=[^']*'?[^']*$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?=[^ ]* ?[^ ]*$)[\p{L} '-]{3,48}$
```